# Transform list items to string

Tags: c#, string, list

In C# I have a list like this:

```
    List<string> cities = new List<string>();
    cities.Add("New York");
    cities.Add("Mumbai");
    cities.Add("Berlin");
    cities.Add("Istanbul");
```

I want to save the items of the list in a string variable like this:

```
string info = "'New York', 'Mumbai', 'Berlin', 'Istanbul'";
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the expected outcome for `"Côte d'Ivoire"` (please, note `'` within the name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Join()` and Linq `Select()`

```
string info = string.Join(", ", cities.Select(x => '\'' + x + '\''));
```

or accoring to Tim's suggestion (C# 6.0)

```
string info = string.Join(", ", cities.Select(c => $"'{c}'"));
```

Comment: Isn't this simpler? `string.Join(", ", cities.Select(c => $"'{c}'"))`

Comment: @TimSchmelter isn't that only for C# 7.0 ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter gracias I've added it as a alternative appraoch

Comment: No, it's C#6 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated